# ¿Cómo puedo importar mis acciones en redux desde una carpeta dentro de los componentes?

Tags: reactjs, rutas, redux

Dentro de mi directorio `src\componentes\escritorio\gastosLista.js`

el siguiente código me da error

```
import {
    establecerTextoFiltros, ordenarPorMonto, ordenarPorFecha
} from '../acciones/filtros';
```

mi problema es como puedo importar el **archivo** `filtros.js` de las `acciones` en Redux con React que se encuentra en el **directorio** 
 `src\acciones\gastos.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acceder desde `'src/componentes/escritorio/fichero.js' a 'src/acciones/filtros.js'` sería así:

`'../../acciones/filtros'`; tienes que "subir" dos niveles el primer `../` te lleva a `'src/componentes/'` el segundo `'../../'` te lleva a `'src/'` y a partir de ahí entras en las carpetas correspondientes.